# Individual variables from the top row of my dataframe are not recognized as objects

Tags: r, dataframe, object, variables

I am really new to "R" and stackoverflow here a beginner question it seems so simple that I can not find the answer in the net...

I loaded my data:

```
df<- read.csv2("HOR.csv", na="NA",header = TRUE)
```

Now I would like to get an overview from individual variables of my df.

I use

```
summary(df)
```

and that works...

But when I try this with individual variables/columns, I get an error

> Object not found

`summary(A)`

eg. the console says:

> Error in summary(PSumme) : Object 'PSumme' not found

It is a very basic question but i can not do any type of analysis since it seems that R does not recognize any of my columns as objects, I get the same error when I try adding or subtracting columns with each others or trying to change variables e.g.:

```
PSumme * -1
```

I have already tried tibble and other commands to turn the columns heads into variables and it seems to work but the variables are not treated as objects.

Bests and ty for your time!

Comment: Try with `summary(df$A)`.

Comment: Ty A LOT this works! do you know of a way that i can skip the "df$" part in other functions for r so that i can just write "a + b"? without having to declare ever of these df$ as an individual variable? also... how can i mark your post as the answer?

Comment: In base R have a look at `with` or `within`, e.g. `within(mtcars, a <- hp + mpg)` will add a variable `a` to the `mtcars` dataframe. Using `dplyr` from the tidyverse you could do the same with `mutate(mtcars, a = hp + mpg)`.